# How can I change the position I want a article in joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla-article

I'm currently developing a website in Joomla, I wanted to know how can I change the location of a article, like all the articles will by the default go in the center position, I wanted to make a article to go to the right position, under my search menu, so I make links there.

Comment: Here's a lot of information about Joomla templates: http://docs.joomla.org/Template_Development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the resolution to my problem by using the module Module as Article joomla module:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/content-embed/7528